# Find missing prefix for computer name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, admin

I am trying to write a script that will automatically find the full asset tag based on the ID of the computer.

For example:

The PC ID is: `PC0001`

```
$computerID = PC0001;
```

But the full asset tag that I need is: `WKSPC0001`

But these asset tags might have different prefixes, for example DSTPC0002, TBLPC0003 etc. But they all have common pattern: Prefix+PC+ID (the ID is unique and there is no repetition).

I am trying to figure out how to write a query for that in PowerShell but I cant figure it out. I've tried:

```
$current = Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "*$computerId.text"} |
           Select -Property Name
```

But I was having issues to get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all "*$computerid.text" will not work because .text will be printed literally and will not allow you to access a property of that variable....

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll fix that when I get a chance. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few observations.

- You want `$computerId` to be a string, so `$computerID = "PC0001";`
- The filter expression for Get-ADComputer is expected to be a string *also*, using curly braces here is wrong. So `Get-ADComputer -Filter "..."`
- Powershell can expand variable values in strings, but it only does that in double-quoted strings. `"Name -like '$variable'"` will work, but `'Name -like "$variable"'` won't.
- There is no `.text` in your `$computerId` variable. It's a plain string.

Knowing that, try:

```
$current = Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$computerId'"
```

Other notes

Don't do `... | Select Name` unless you really must. Storing the computer object itself will be more versatile. You can do `$current.Name` when you need it anytime.

Querying the AD with a filter that begins with a wildcard is ***slow***. Try to avoid.

If you have a fixed number of possible prefixes, an [LDAP filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) like the following will be *much* faster:

```
$current = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter "(|(cn=WKS$computerId)(cn=DST$computerId)(cn=TBL$computerId))"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it out tomorrow morning. I owe you one :)

Comment: Also look at the LDAP filter variant I just added. It's the better approach.

Comment: Using curly brackets for the filter expression is not technically wrong (it's actually valid syntax). However, the expression is still handled as a string, not as a scriptblock, so the behavior is frequently different from what people expect. Hence it's recommended to actually write it as a string.

Comment: Hm, I see... Is there any problem that the curly-brace variant can solve and the string variant cannot?

Comment: Not that I know of. It's rather the opposite. Like I said, using the string form is actually what I recommend. I have no idea what the people at Microsoft were thinking when the came up with a scriptblock-ish notation for this particular parameter and I consider it a really bad design choice.